# Can I use django as a front end for an already existing database?

Tags: mysql, database, django

I have a database populated with data that I want to present as a website. It will be read-only and I was wondering if there was a standard way of presenting the data using `django`'s forms and template syntax to make my job easier.

I could code up a site with `php` but I was wondering if it was possible from an alternative language. I suppose this question could be extended to other web frameworks eg. ruby on rails. My background is with `python` so a `django` answer would be preferable.

I am not concerned with administering the database as it is out of my hands (I only have read-only access anyway).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

["Integrating Django with a legacy database"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/)

Comment: thank you really should have googled more thoroughly, though I would have never think of searching for "legacy"!